# How to tell the difference between two usb drives in "Use a device" windows 10 boot disk "The Advanced Startup Options Menu"?

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb

Say I have two different USB disks plugged into one machine and I hold down the shift key so I enter a windows 10 startup disk and select `Advanced Startup Options`, then I select `Use a device` see below:

[image: Choose an Option from Advanced Startup Options]

My goal is to boot from one of two USB devices, but I don't know which one is which when I select it to boot from.

I've run a command that prints the serial number (but it doesn't seem to match between using `diskpart.exe` and using `Get-Disk` in PowerShell it seems to yield a different serial number in each.  I understand you can also use `wmic` to obtain that.

After clicking `Use a device` there's like a million options on the screen...I just want a unique identifier maybe for instance the serial number of the volume or something like that:

[image: A million options for booting, but none of them are for instance a volume with this serial number]

[image: More devices more wasted time trying to find my drives...]

None of these line up with a unique identifier of any sort.  It should just list the identifier and then you're sure you're selecting the correct drive to boot from.  Is there a way to tell that?  Or maybe a cmdline way to "choose a device"?

I'm also unclear as to if these things boot using ufi or legacy, because both drives are listed as `mbr` not `gpt` in diskpart, but both drives also have `.efi` files in them.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't unplug the devices that are not desired?

Comment: @InterLinked well the HDD is internal and I can’t take it apart; it’s not a tower, it’s more like an all in one device.

Comment: @InterLinked I can unplug the USB drives though.